# Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed python

Tags: python, sockets, web-scraping, errno

I am currently trying to get files from [this site](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time) from the years 2004 - 2015.  However, I am getting an error while trying to download the data.

```
import datetime
from os import rename
from os.path import splitext
from calendar import month_name
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from time import clock
from urllib import urlretrieve
from zipfile import ZipFile
import numpy as np

import os
import errno
import humanize
import sys

from data_scraper import *

def main():
    # first create cache directory if it does not exist
    cache_path = os.path.join('/', 'cache')
    create_dir(cache_path)

    # check if the dictionary for file urls exists
    url_dict_file = 'url_dict.json'
    if not file_exists(os.path.join(cache_path, url_dict_file)):
        # will retrieve urls for 25 years (change here if necessary)
        get_file_urls(cache_path)

    # read urldict
    urldict = {}
    with open(os.path.join(cache_path, url_dict_file)) as infile:
         urldict = json.load(infile)

    # download 10 years of data as zip files
    dates = get_year_tuples(list(np.arange(2004, 2015)))
    download_zip_files(dates, urldict, cache_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: `socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com",80)` your module not provided any high level command, so need use a `request` module(not base).

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace please.